# In addition to username and password, can client ID and secret be considered as a multi-factor authentication?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, api

Two-factor or multi-factor authentication is based on three possible forms of authentication:

1. Something you know
2. Something you have
3. Something you are

Since username and password are considered as "something you know", can a client ID and secret sent as part of an API request be considered "something you have" as it is generated by the client? However, the client secret is not entirely dynamic like an OTP unless the client regenerates the client secret.

Comment: I think that you are trying to push the ideas further than they allow and you have some misconceptions. First, there are more than 3 forms. Second, usernames are often public, so it is not under "something you know". Third, "something you have" does not cover secrets.

Comment: And lastly, why does the answer matter? What problem are you trying to solve? This looks like a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).